# Handle Multithreaded Processes

Tags: c#, vmware

This is my first experience with multi-threaded processes and I am having difficulty understanding how things are working.

Here is my scenario:

I have a list of servers about 15 long. I then put each server in a list by the vCenter it belongs to. Therefore if I have about 15 servers and 5 vCenters then it has to loop through the serverList at least 3 times to set each server to its vCenter. Once the code below executes it removes the server from the server list.

```
List<Server> serverList = new List<Server>();

//populate vCenters using the serverList

foreach(vCenter v in vCenters)
{ 
     //Connect to the vCenter and bring back data
     //remove the server from the serverList
}
```

The problem is that each call is not waiting for the previous one to finish and because of this the serverList is not staying consistent because the first server connects then the second server connects then the first server brings back data. Obviously there is some multi threading going on here. However I want to be able to say to have each vCenter connect and bring back data and hold off on everything else until all vCenters have brought back data. Can anyone give me a good suggestion on how to do this? I have looked at tasks and threading but it doesnt seem to be doing what I expect it to.

**EDIT**

Here is how I currently am handling it

```
public void getData()
{
    foreach(vCenter vCenter1 in vCenters)
    {
         VimClient client = connectToVC(vCenter1);
         NameValueCollection vmFilter = new NameValueCollection();
         vmFilter.Add("name", hostName);
         VirtualMachine vm = (VirtualMachine)client.FindEntityView(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, vmFilter, null);
         Console.WriteLine("cpu", getVMSpec(vm, "vCPU"));
         Console.WriteLine("mem", getVMSpec(vm, "Mem"));

    }

}

public String getVMSpec(VirtualMachine vm, String type)
    {
        if(type.Equals("vCPU"))
            return vm.Summary.Config.NumCpu.ToString();
        return vm.Summary.Config.MemorySizeMB.ToString();
    }

Action<object> action = (object obj) =>
{
    getData();
};
System.Threading.Tasks.Task t1 = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(action, "gettingData");
t1.Wait();
```

Ideally getData would do a multithreaded process to each vCenter and bring back the data into one thread to continue with the application and only split the threads when the getData method is called.

**EDIT2**

```
        while (Queue.Count > 0 || isVCentersEmpty() == false)
        {
            setVCenters(); // sets the vCenter buckets to any available servers from the Queue

            Console.WriteLine("Begin getData");
            var result = Parallel.ForEach(vCenters, getData);               
            while (!result.IsCompleted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("gettingData...");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("End getData");
        }
```

This is my new function per your parrallel idea however "begin getData" is being outputted more than once before End getData which makes me think there is still another thread running alongside this. any ideas? thanks for the help!

**Edit 3**

```
List<Server> Queue = [server1]... [server15]

List<vCenter> vCenters = [vCenter1] ... [vCenter5]
```

There are 15 servers and 5 vCenters.

```
while (Queue.Count > 0 || isVCentersEmpty() == false)
{
    setVCenters(); // sets the vCenter buckets to any available servers from the Queue

    Console.WriteLine("Begin getData");
    var result = Parallel.ForEach(vCenters, rightsize);               
    while (!result.IsCompleted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Getting Data...");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("End getData");
 }
```

Comment: You need to show _how_ you `Connect to the vCenter and bring back data`.

Comment: Added more code to demonstrate the flow

Comment: VimClient client = connectToVC(vCenter1) ... shouldn't that be VimClient client = connectToVC(v)? Otherwise, they're all connecting to the same instance.

Comment: I changed v to vCenter1 -> I apologize I did not copy over exactly as it is and I used the wrong variable name. -thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, you're on the wrong track; you need to create a thread for each vCenter, not have the thread that you create loop through the list of vCenters. You can also use the TPL to make use of the cores of your machine, it might make this simpler to understand.

change getData to accept a vCenter as a param:

```
    public void getData(vCenter v)
    {
        VimClient client = connectToVC(v);
        NameValueCollection vmFilter = new NameValueCollection();
        vmFilter.Add("name", hostName);
        VirtualMachine vm = (VirtualMachine)client.FindEntityView(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, vmFilter, null);
        Console.WriteLine("cpu", getVMSpec(vm, "vCPU"));
        Console.WriteLine("mem", getVMSpec(vm, "Mem"));
    }
```

You can then let the TPL go out and handle each vCenter like so:

```
    var result = Parallel.ForEach(vCenters, getData);

    while (!result.IsCompleted)
    {
        //do some other work; this is your main controlling thread.
    }
```

Comment: does it have to be a static method?

Comment: No, I typed it up quickly in a console app. You can take static out. I'll edit it.

Comment: You've got the call to Parallel.ForEach inside a while loop; you would see the "begin getData" if the Queue.Count > 0 or isVCentersEmpty() is false. Where is the Queue count being reduced / what is setting the isVCentersEmpty to false?

Comment: Each time getData is completed a method looks for a server and places it in its corresponding vCenter bucket. Then the getData is ran again. Shouldnt all the getData's be completed once the while is finished?

Comment: All the getData's will be completed once the result.IsCompleted flag is true. I guess I may not be seeing the flow ... I don't see where anything is being removed.

Comment: I made another edit. setVCenters is taking a server from the Queue, adding it to that vCenter bucket and doing getData on it. This continues until the Queue is empty. I want each run to be completed before the next run takes place. I.E. I want all the getDatas for each list of vCenters to be completed before a new list of vCenters is populated with more servers from the Queue

Comment: Then you would expect to see the console messages multiple times, no? Once for each item in the queue?

Comment: I would expect Begin, End, Begin, End. What I am seeing is Begin, Begin, End Begin, End

Comment: Unless there are multiple threads calling the function with your queue loop, that shouldn't happen; it's not your getData calls that are the issue, its further up the chain than that.